# How to Hold Old Array Index Position After Filtering ListView

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-listview, filter

I have a `EditText` and `ListView` on MainActiviy. `EditText` for search and filter `ListView`'s items.

I have two arrays;

newspapers[ ] holds some newspaper name,

adress[ ]     holds web adress of newspapers.

Also I have a `setOnItemClickListener`. In listener I get position of item and with help of this index number of array I fetch adress info from `adress[ ]` array.

First there was no search box for filter. I added `addTextChangedListener` to EditText to filter ListView's items. Problem started here!

When I write something to search box it is filtering properly, but after filtering if I click to any item it opens old item's address.

Example:

Assume,

A

B

C

D

are item before filter and A item's in array position is 0, B=1, C=2, D=3

**if I write to search "C" only C is visible after filtering and if I click "C" item it opens A's web site. Because "A" item was first item before filtering.**

***How can I update array index positions after filtering ListView?***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;

// Listview Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

protected static final String SITE_ADDRESS = null;
// protected static final String SITE_NAME = null;

private ListView newspaper_list_view;

private String[] newspapers = { "A","B","C","D" };

private String[] adress = { "a.com","b.com","c.com","d.com" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    newspaper_list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gazeteliste);
    adapter             = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newspapers);
    newspaper_list_view.setAdapter(adapter);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, GazeteIcerik.class);

    newspaper_list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int listposition, long arg3) {

            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Liste Sırası:" +
            // listposition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String site_adress = adress[listposition];
            String site_name   = newspapers[listposition];

            intent.putExtra(SITE_ADDRESS, site_adress);
            // intent.putExtra(SITE_NAME, site_name);
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            intent.putExtra(SITE_ADDRESS, new String[] { site_adress,site_name });
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

}

// onCreate sonu

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using two separate arrays for newspapers and addresses, that's the cause of the issue. Currently, you're only filtering newspaper array, but address array stays same. That's why you're getting old item's address. There are two different things you can do to fix this.

1. (Easy one) Create a hash map for addresses and use newspaper name as the key and address as the value, so you can get the correct address in any case.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
  HashMap<String, String> addressMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); // initialize the hashmap

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    newspaper_list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int listposition, long arg3) {
          String name   = newspapers[listposition];
          String address = addressMap.get(name);
       }
    });
  }
}
```

1. (More complicated, choose only if you need to add more features to your listview) Or you can create a custom object that stores newspaper and address and a custom adapter to filter the listview.

Comment: is it necessary CustomAdapter with HashMap or can I implement it ArrayAdapter?

Comment: With hashmap, option 1, you can still use ArrayAdapter.